# Device Description Vocabulary

Tags: rdf, owl, wurfl, rdfs

I asked a more general question a while back and didn't get any responses but am still going to persevere. Does anyone know of a vocabulary/ontology for describe digital devices with web browsers? I am talking about something in RDF (RDFS or OWL). I came across the following:

http://www.w3.org/TR/ddr-core-vocabulary/

But it doesn't seem very relevant or current.

Additionally (and this might answer the above). Does anyone know anyone who has transformed the WURFL repository into RDF. I think these questions are synonymous so I haven't split them apart.

Answer (score 0):

One of the problems of RDF is that an ontology is much less useful if it's not standard. You can use it to describe data, but other tools won't use it and won't share it, because they won't even be aware of it.

I don't know any ontology of this kind. I guess a good idea would be to write your own. There's an ongoing effort by many organizations, especially academic/nonprofit ones, to standardize ontologies for many fields. So another good suggestion I have: contact people, find key organizations and share your ideas. This is the key to a standard ontology accepted and used by everyone, and thus implements the full power of semantic web and semantic desktop.

By the way, there are loads of ontologies on the web, but many of them are written by propeietary bodies and are specifically written for their use, so if you use an existing one, make sure it's written with semantic web in mind, share-the-knowledge style. A low-quality limited ontology would quickly become a burden to use.